# Use Interpolating Function in Expression

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, nonlinear

I am new to Mathematica and am doing work involving interpolating functions from [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html).  I would like to use the interpolating functions from [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)in calculations but I can't seem to figure out the proper way to do this.  So say I have the following interpolating function:

```
myInt = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 3}, {4, 2}, {7, 9}}]
```

> `InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 7}}, <>]`

I would then like to take this interpolating function and use it like a variable or function and perform math operations on it like:

```
modMyInt = myInt*3 + 1
```

> `1 + 3 InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 7}}, <>]`

But when I plot `modMyInt` I get an empty plot.

```
Plot[modMyInt[t], {t, 0, 9}]
```

I think I am misunderstanding what interpolating functions are; can someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: Try `modMyInt = myInt[t]*3 + 1; Plot[modMyInt, {t, 0, 9}]`. You can't do arithmetic operations with interpolation functions, but you can include them in expressions. Interpolation functions are black boxes; things like addition and multiplication are not defined for  them.

Answer (score 2):

This is really just an issue with how to define functions in Mathematica.  Most intuitive is with rules (though there are other ways):

```
modMyInt[t_] = myInt[t]*3 + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
eqn1 = x''[t] == Sin[t]*y[t] + t;
eqn2 = y''[t] == Sin[t]*x[t] + t;

sol = NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == -0.2, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]}, 
              {t, 0, 10}];

{xsol, ysol} = sol[[1, All, 2]];

modMyInt = 3*xsol + 1;

Plot[modMyInt, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```